# How to determine headers being passed downstream in Azure App Service reverse proxy?

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, reverse-proxy

I have a ASP.NET MVC website hosted in Azure App Service.

I've also configured my site to act as a reverse proxy, for certain paths.

e.g

- www.mysite.com => mvc handles
- www.mysite.com/blog => iis reverse proxy handles, passing to downstream system

I'm trying to determine what HTTP Headers are being passed to the downstream system, for these paths that are being proxied.

How can i do this?

I know we can log *inbound* headers into IIS (request logs), but what about *outbound* headers that get proxied to a downstream system?

Context: downstream system is saying i'm not passing through `X-Forwarded-For` header, so i'm trying to confirm that.

Comment: Have you checked FRT yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: It's not a failed request?

Comment: FRT is just the name. It works for all requests.